# Why image is not zooming in or out

Tags: javascript, animation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img onmouseover="increasesz()" onmouseout="decreasesz()" src="1.jpg" width="1000px" id="img1">
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var width = 1000;
    var Id = 0;
    var a = 2;
    function increasesz()
    {
        Id = setInterval(expand,20);
    }
    function expand()
    {
        if(width<1200)
        {
            width = width + a;
            document.getElementById("img1").style.width = width;
        }else{
            clearInterval(Id);
        }
    }
    function decreasesz()
    {
        Id = setInterval(shrink,20);
    }
    function shrink()
    {
        document.getElementById("img1").style.width = width;
        if(width>1000)
        {
            width = width - a;
            document.getElementById("img1").style.width = width;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Its image zoom in and zoom out animation in JS . Not working. Can anyone find the error?

Comment: Why is your script tag outside `html` tag?

Comment: `.style.width` needs units - width attribute does not - your a*sed-about when you do/don't need units

Comment: oh, and you may get some funky things happening if you hover then leave before the width is 1200 .... this is far better done with pure CSS `:hover` and CSS transitions

Answer (score 0):

**Here some change that worked:**

1. change width into pixels (width+"px")
2. clear the decress interval id

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img onmouseover="increasesz()" onmouseout="decreasesz()" src="https://picsum.photos/200" width="1000px" id="img1">
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var width = 1000;
    var Id = 0;
    var a = 2;
    function increasesz()
    {
      
        Id = setInterval(expand,20);
    }
    function expand()
    {
        if(width<1200)
        {
            width = width + a;
            document.getElementById("img1").style.width = width+"px";
        }else{
            clearInterval(Id);
        }
    }

    function decreasesz()
    {
        Id = setInterval(shrink,20);
    }
    function shrink()
    {
        document.getElementById("img1").style.width = width+"px";
        if(width>1000)
        {
            width = width - a;
            document.getElementById("img1").style.width = width+"px";
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(Id);
        }
    }
</script>
```